# The BeautifulSoup object isn't fetching <ul> tags with class set to comments. Any suggestions?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib
>>> url = "http://www.securitytube.net/video/7313"
>>> 
>>> page = urllib.urlopen(url)
>>> 
>>> pageDom = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

On running the above code, I receive the dom object in the 'pageDom' variable. Now I do this (code mentioned below) and I get an empty list.

```
>>> allComments = pageDom.find_all("ul", class_="comments")
>>> 
>>> allComments
[]
>>> 
>>>
```

So now I removed 'class_' and am able to fetch all the unordered list tags.
Check the code below.

```
>>> allComments = pageDom.find_all("ul")
>>> len(allComments)
27
>>>
```

If I look at the source code of the page I can very well see all the < ul > with the class as "comments". I don't know where am I missing stuffs. I also tried changing the parser to "lxml" but no joy.
Any suggestions/ improvements will be highly appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a difference from the versions but here is the code and the output that worked fine with Python 3.4:

```
url = "http://www.securitytube.net/video/7313"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
pageDom = BeautifulSoup(page)
#print(pageDom)
#On running the above code, I receive the dom object in the 'pageDom' variable. Now I do this (code mentioned below) and I get an empty list.

allComments = pageDom.find_all("ul", class_="comments")
#print(allComments)
print(len(allComments))
#So now I removed 'class_' and am able to fetch all the unordered list tags. Check the code below.

allComments = pageDom.find_all("ul")
#print(allComments)
print(len(allComments))
```

Output:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/{path}/testPython.py
2
27

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You can uncomment the print lines to see the array contents

Comment: I'm working with python 2.7.3, it shouldn't make any difference however as you tested I can't deny. I'll check the same on my end as well. Kudos for the reply. Its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tested (multiple times) in python 2.7 32 bit-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
url = "http://www.securitytube.net/video/7313"

page = urllib.urlopen(url)
page = d=page.read()
pageDom = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
allComments = pageDom.find_all("ul", class_="comments")
print len(allComments)
allComments = pageDom.find_all("ul")
print len(allComments)
```

It prints-

```
2
27
```